# Problem with sorting bibliography alphabetically

Tags: natbib

I'm having a problem sorting the bibliography in alphabetical order, I'm using `natbib`, here is a code overview:

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{allbiblio/allbiblio}
```

I'm using TeXnicCenter/MiKTeX distribution, on Windows 7.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french]{book}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[francais]{babel} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{pdfpages} \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,epsfig,epstopdf,titling,url,array} 
\usepackage[round]{natbib} 
\begin{document} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
\bibliography{allbiblio/allbiblio} 
\end{document}
```

And part of file `allbiblio.bib`:

```
@book{c1r1, 
  title={Should we be using learning styles? What research has to say to practice}, 
  author={Coffield, Frank}, 
  year={2004}, 
  publisher={Learning and Skills Research Centre} 
} 

@book{c1r2, 
  title={The Myers-Briggs Type Indicator: Form G}, 
  author={Briggs, Katharine Cook and Myers, Isabel Briggs}, 
  year={1977}, 
  publisher={Consulting Psychologists Press} 
} 

@book{c1r3, 
  title={Experiential learning: Experience as the source of learning and development}, 
  author={Kolb, David A}, 
  year={2014}, 
  publisher={FT press} 
}
```

Comment: I never used the `natbib` package with the `plainnat` style but I guess that the entries are sorted alphabetically by default. It would be easier to help you if you gave us a working example. Which commands did you use to compile your document?

Comment: i've edited the code from your comment into the question.  when you have additions to a question, you can always add them there yourself, even if you are new to the site.  extended code in comments is *very* hard to interpret.

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: @Thorsten - The `natbib` package offers the bib styles `plainnat`, `unsrtnat`, and `abbrvnat`. They provide the exact same formatting of bib entries as the venerable styles `plain`, `unsrt`, and `abbrv` do. Relative to the "original" styles, the styles of the `natbib` package offer two important advantages: (a) one can do authoryear-style and superscript-style citation callouts, and not just numeric-style citation call-outs; and (b) the style files recognize and process additional fields such as `url`, `doi`, `isbn`, and `issn`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you asked for "sorting the bibliography in alphabetical order".

If I compile your given code with my **current** MiKTeX 2.9 distribution, after adding a command `\nocite{*}` to get a printed bibliography, I get an alphabetical order.

Please see the following MWE (I commented all packages not needed to show the problem):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{c1r1, 
  title={Should we be using learning styles? What research has to say to practice}, 
  author={Coffield, Frank}, 
  year={2004}, 
  publisher={Learning and Skills Research Centre}, 
} 

@book{c1r2, 
  title={The Myers-Briggs Type Indicator: Form G}, 
  author={Briggs, Katharine Cook and Myers, Isabel Briggs}, 
  year={1977}, 
  publisher={Consulting Psychologists Press}, 
} 

@book{c1r3, 
  title={Experiential learning: Experience as the source of learning and development}, 
  author={Kolb, David A}, 
  year={2014}, 
  publisher={FT press}, 
} 
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[a4paper,french]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[francais]{babel} 

%\usepackage{lipsum} 
%\usepackage{graphicx} 
%\usepackage{float} 
%\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs} 
%\usepackage{caption} 
%\usepackage{wrapfig} 
%\usepackage{multirow} 
%\usepackage{pdfpages} 
%\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,epsfig,epstopdf,titling,url,array} 
\usepackage[round]{natbib} 


\begin{document}
\nocite{*} % <================================================== missing
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
\bibliography{\jobname} % <======= to use bib file created with filecontents
\end{document}
```

That gives me the following result:

[image]

As you can see the entries are sorted: B, C, K

If I missunderstand your question please update your question to clarify your question!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a similar issue. I was wondering if it would be possible to sort by the first name of the author: David, Frank, Katherine.  @Mensch