# Unsuccessful attempts at sorting the bibliography alphabetically [natbib,plainnat,citep]

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texlive, natbib, sorting

After consulting lots of posts here at tex exchange and other resources, I still can't figure out the problem. Everything looks fine, still alphabetical sorting in working for me. This is the last important step to finish my thesis, and wonder some of the experienced people can help me.

Linked posts:
[Sort bibliography alphabetically with \citep command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78773/sort-bibliography-alphabetically-with-citep-command)

[Alphabetical order in natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98027/alphabetical-order-in-natbib)

[Problem with sorting bibliography alphabetically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301740/problem-with-sorting-bibliography-alphabetically)

[Different order for citations and the bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62408/different-order-for-citations-and-the-bibliography)

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11.5pt,
               headsepline,
               BCOR=40mm, american, %paper=a4,ngerman,
               bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}

# loading natbib
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

# using plainnat to sort it alphabetically 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

# using references from two different files
\bibliography{Bibliography/introMethods,Bibliography/resultsDiscussion}
```

Entries from my reference files (all in bibtex format)

```
@article{roguev2001saccharomyces,
  title={The Saccharomyces cerevisiae Set1 complex includes an Ash2 homologue and methylates histone 3 lysine 4},
  author={Roguev, Assen and Schaft, Daniel and Shevchenko, Anna and Pijnappel, WWM Pim and Wilm, Matthias and Aasland, Rein and Stewart, A Francis},
  journal={The EMBO journal},
  volume={20},
  number={24},
  pages={7137--7148},
  year={2001},
  publisher={EMBO Press}
}

@article{miller2001compass,
  title={COMPASS: a complex of proteins associated with a trithorax-related SET domain protein},
  author={Miller, Trissa and Krogan, Nevan J and Dover, Jim and Erdjument-Bromage, H and Tempst, Paul and Johnston, Mark and Greenblatt, Jack F and Shilatifard, Ali},
  journal={Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
  volume={98},
  number={23},
  pages={12902--12907},
  year={2001},
  publisher={National Acad Sciences}
}
```

I calling within text using citep `~\citep{roguev2001saccharomyces}`

These entries look fine as someone mentioned in the other post, to reformat the author name.

I using TexLive beta for ElCaptain (MacOSX) complied via `pdflatex` using TexStudio. I have also deleted .bbl,.blg,.aux files before regenerating the bibliography. There are total of around 250 references in both the files. I mostly used google schlolar to export the citations of scientific papers in the bibtex format.

Please let me know, if I am missing any information and I will add up here.
Thanks a lot and have a great day!

How the output looks like
[image]

**Update:** 
Thanks to Ulrike for pointing out that the references are already sorted and problem with other references. First two entries have no author name, that's why they are not sorted. But for the third entry (Agger) I want it like this:

[image]

Minimal working example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
Lets cite this reference \citep{roguev2001saccharomyces} and this ~\citep{miller2001compass}.
\printindex

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{temp.bib} % Insert the name of your bib file here

\end{document}
```

Contents of temp.bib

```
@article{roguev2001saccharomyces,
  title={The Saccharomyces cerevisiae Set1 complex includes an Ash2 homologue and methylates histone 3 lysine 4},
  author={Roguev, Assen and Schaft, Daniel and Shevchenko, Anna and Pijnappel, WWM Pim and Wilm, Matthias and Aasland, Rein and Stewart, A Francis},
  journal={The EMBO journal},
  volume={20},
  number={24},
  pages={7137--7148},
  year={2001},
  publisher={EMBO Press}
}

@article{miller2001compass,
  title={COMPASS: a complex of proteins associated with a trithorax-related SET domain protein},
  author={Miller, Trissa and Krogan, Nevan J and Dover, Jim and Erdjument-Bromage, H and Tempst, Paul and Johnston, Mark and Greenblatt, Jack F and Shilatifard, Ali},
  journal={Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
  volume={98},
  number={23},
  pages={12902--12907},
  year={2001},
  publisher={National Acad Sciences}
}
```

Generates 
[image]

I want to change the order of first name and last name and the first author name to be bold, for ex:
[image]

Comment: Agger, Allfrey, Allis is alphabetical. If you want to know why "Gdelt Project" comes first you will have to show the relevant bib entry.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike, You are right, Gdelt project has no author name.
I have updated my answer, how I want to see my bibliography. Could you help in that regard. I want the following for the first entry, actually that's why I couldn't figure it out, that it was already alphabetically sorted as I was looking at the first word. 

Agger K, Christensen J, Cloos PA, Helin K (2008) The emerging functions of histone demethylases. Current opinion in genetics & development 18: 159-168

Comment: Make a complete example, including the bib entries. I don't want to spent my time to expand your snippets to setup a test environment.

Comment: I updated with a MWE and .bib entries.

Comment: I think its already answered here, so I will get the hints and try to work it out. Thanks for your help.
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131087/displaying-authors-name-in-a-bibliographic-entry-in-the-form-surname-first-in